# Could Not Round the float value to the nearest second decimal even after using "\n%.2f" in C

Tags: c++, c

After typing the below code, the temperature in Kelvin is output to be **.2**273.14995. Hence the **".2"** used in **"\n%.2f"** has appeared in the output value of Kelvin, which should ideally be 273.14995. The Fahrenheit conversion is rounded up perfectly to 2 decimal places, but why isn't the Kelvin conversion?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  float x,y,z;
  printf("Enter The Temperature In Celsius:\n ");
  scanf("%f", &x);
  y=(x*9/5)+32;
  z=x+273.15;
  printf("\nThe Temperature in Fahrenheit And Kelvin Respectively Are: \n%.2f \n\n%.2f",y,z);
}
```

[Here a screenshot of the running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvAx9.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does your question look loke you wanted it to? (I hope it does not.) Please take a look at [How do I format my post using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Additionally, please do not add pure text output as an image; copy the text and paste it as such in your code.

Comment: Compare the `printf` you posted here against the one in the linked image. Hint: always copy/paste the actual code in the question, do _not_ retype it.

Comment: `9/5` is an integer division that yields 1. I doubt that `x`, `y` and `z` are good variable names for the temperature in Fahrenheit, Celsius and Kelvin.

Comment: The code you're using is different to the code you're showing us. That's a _big_ no no. -1

Comment: Sorry Guys ! My Bad % should be before .2 and not after it. Thanks for helping me out , I Am a Newbie , Sorry Again for committing such a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Please take in considerations the advice from Jongware in the first place, that will be great.

Now for the actual code, when you use decimal number you might want to use it everywhere (for example the line `y=(x*9/5)+32`, could be better like this `y = (x * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0`). But for your problem, the thing is that the first time you're doing it right `%.2f`, but the second time you miss-placed the `%`, it should be before the `.2` and not after. ;)

Hope this helps !

Comment: You're welcome, but please take in consideration that your topic was put "on hold".